# Ordinary smooth boundary point - what is the proper terminology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I have a bounded region in the euclidean plane.

I'm looking for the proper terminology for an ordinary, smooth boundary point of the region... ie: it's not a corner and it's not a cutpoint.

So if the region is a square, it would be the points of the boundary other than the corners. If the region is a figure 8, it would the points of the boundary other than the self-intersection point of the boundary.

What's the proper terminology in topology for such a point on the boundary?

Comment: There is no topological way of describing smoothness.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, what about outside topology. Is there any special term for the type of boundary point I'm referring to?

Comment: A smooth curve is a curve that can differentiated infinitely times.